# Valgrind и realloc

Tags: valgrind, realloc

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему Valgrind'у не нравится realloc во внешней функции real? В данном коде нет проверки равен ли указатель на массив NULL, но это ничего не меняет.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* заполняем массив данными */
void paste(int* a, int s) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<s; ++i)
    a[i]=i+1;
}

/* выводим на экран*/
void show(int* a, int s) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<s; ++i)
    printf("%d; ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

/* расширяем массив realloc'ом */
void real(int* a, int s)
{
    a=(int*)realloc(a, s*sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
    int s=3;

    int* a=(int*)malloc(s*sizeof(int));

    paste(a,s);

    show(a, s);

    s+=3;

    real(a,s);

    paste(a,s);

    show(a,s);

    free(a);    
}
```

Comment: Вы внутри `real` изменили локальную переменную `a`, а вот переменная `a` внутри функции `main` осталась иметь старое значение. В итоге вы пишете в уже освобождённую память, и то, что программа не взорвалась тонной непредсказуемых ошибок — счастливая случайность

Comment: @andreymal, ответы - в ответы. Кстати, присваивание всё равно плохое - память течёт, если там null.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не подскажите как правильно реализовать такой подход, я имею в виду realloc вне main?

Comment: Банально вернуть новое значение из функции, наверное?

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал так real(&a, s); и внутри ф-ции real вот так *a=(int*)realloc(*a, s*sizeof(int)); Отработало без ошибок.